# Error: 1553 - AQL: bind parameter '@myParameter' has an invalid value or type (while parsing) - ERROR_QUERY_BIND_PARAMETER_TYPE

Tags: java, arangodb

I have the following query:

```
FOR i IN items
    COLLECT otherId = i._from WITH COUNT INTO counter
    FILTER counter > @@myParameter
    RETURN otherId
```

Doesn't matter if it's executed from Java or the ArangoDB Web Interface, I always get the same error back: 
**Query: AQL: bind parameter '@myParameter' has an invalid value or type (while parsing)**

If I replace *@@myParameter* with a number it works.

Any idea? In Java I have tried with Integer, Long, BigInteger with no luck :-(

ArangoDB COMMUNITY EDITION v3.2.5

Comment: I think you need to use a single @ for non-collection parameters. https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/fundamentals-bind-parameters.html It would be helpful if you would provide the complete call including the bind object.

Comment: Yes, that's the fix! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Non-collection parameters require a single @